# Refer to the same footnote using two different markers

Tags: footnotes

I'd like to have two different footnote markers referring to the same footnote. I want the footnote at the bottom of the page to be "marker 1, marker 2 text" instead of "marker 1 text" line break "marker 2 text". I know this isn't recommended but it's for a specific situation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\title{Example}
\author{Example Author 1 \thanks{footnote text} %
    \and Example Author 2 \thanks{footnote text}
}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\title{Example}
\author{Example Author 1 \footnotemark[1] %
    \and Example Author 2 \footnotemark[2] }

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newcounter{mycounter}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{mycounter}}
\footnotetext[1]{\makeatletter\setcounter{footnote}{0}\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}{\footnotemark[1]},{\footnotemark[2]}\makeatother  my text}
\setcounter{footnote}{0}\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}

\newpage
Here will be another footenote\footnote{test}
\end{document}
```

It is just a trick but works if you don't have other footnotes in the same page

Here is the titlepage:

[image: trickFootnotes]

Comment: You are welcome.... If you want you can accept the answer... Or you can wait for a better one